# Doesn`t work method create for serializers.ModelSerializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I study Django Rest Framework. First I created `CustomUser` Model based on `AbstractUser`. After I created serializer `RegistrationSerializer` based on `ModelSerializer`. In `RegistrationSerializer` I wrote my own `create()` for `password2` validation using official specification.
Extra field for `password2` works well. But my `RegistrationSerializer` "doesn't use" my `create()`. Looks like it doesn`t know about method and I can`t understand why. On my POST request without `password2` I recieve password2 is required. On my POST request with `password2` I recieve CustomUser() got an unexpected keyword argument 'password2'.

```
accounts/models.py

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
        image = models.ImageField(verbose_name="Аватар", upload_to="covers/", null=True)
```

And

```
accounts / api / serialers.py
from rest_framework import serializers
from accounts.models import CustomUser

class RegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password2 = serializers.CharField(style={'input_type': 'password'}, write_only=True)

class Meta:
    model = CustomUser

    fields = ['email', 'username', 'password', 'password2']
    extra_kwargs = {
        'password': {'write_only': True},
    }

    def create(self):
        account = CustomUser(
            email=self.validated_data['email'],
            username=self.validated_data['username']
        )
        password = self.validated_data['password']
        password2 = self.validated_data['password2']
        if password != password2:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'password': 'Passwords must match.'})
        account.set_password(password)
        account.save()
        return account
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have indented `create` in the wrong way, try this:

```
class RegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password2 = serializers.CharField(style={'input_type': 'password'}, write_only=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['email', 'username', 'password', 'password2']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only': True},
        }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        account = CustomUser(
            email=validated_data['email'],
            username=validated_data['username']
        )
        password = validated_data['password']
        password2 = validated_data['password2']
        if password != password2:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'password': 'Passwords must match.'})
        account.set_password(password)
        account.save()
        return account
```

When you want to create a CustomUser instance you can write:

```
serializer = RegistrationSerializer(data={'email': 'example@gmail.com', 'username': 'example', 'password': 'Password0', 'password2': 'Password0'})
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
serializer.save()
```